# How can I determine if a PDO statement cursor is closed?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a search class that keeps prepared PDO statements around for re-execution with new parameters each time the search is run. A conflict occurs if a second search is run while a previous search still has a result set open and is returning results. What I'd like to do in this case is simply create and execute a new statement rather than reusing the open one.

Is there a way to determine if PDOStatement has had `closeCursor()` called on it or that all records have been fetched?

Alternatively, how can I determine if more results are available in a PDOStatement without advancing past the next result?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply call closeCursor(), regardless of whether or not there are still results pending?

Comment: I'd like to keep returning results from the fist cursor, so I don't want to close it.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question, it might be the kind of thing you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531536/php-orm-query-results-arrays-vs-result-handle-wrapped-in-iterator-interface